# Why is the last dollar change calculation wrong

Tags: java, calculator, division, difference, modulus

Why is the last calculation printing out the wrong calculation. 
here is my code:

```
System.out.print("Enter total cost: ");

double totalCost = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("The Customer has paid: ");
double customerAmount = input.nextDouble();

//Calculations
double changeOwed = customerAmount - totalCost;
System.out.println("Change owed: $"+(int)changeOwed);

int amountFifty = (int)changeOwed/50;
System.out.println("How many $50 notes = " +amountFifty);

int takeAway = (int)changeOwed - (amountFifty * 50);

int amount20 = takeAway / 20;
System.out.println("How many $20 notes = " +amount20);

int amount10 = (takeAway - amount20*20) / 10;
System.out.println("How many $10 notes = " +amount10);
enter code here
int amount5 = (takeAway - amount10*10) / 5;
System.out.println("How many $5 notes = " +amount5);

int amount2 = (takeAway - amount5*5) / 2;
System.out.println("How many $2 notes = " +amount2);

int amount1 = (takeAway - amount2*2) /1;
System.out.printl

n("How many $1 notes = " +amount1);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the last calculation? Can you edit your question to include your expected output and your actual output.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you're trying to do? What is the expected output here? What is showing up instead of the expected output?

Comment: Do not use double for currency - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/2670892)

Answer (score 2):

You are not keeping track of the change you have issued along the way correctly.

```
int takeAway = (int)changeOwed - (amountFifty * 50);
```

The line above correctly calculates what's left after you determine the number of $50 bills required. This means that:

```
int amount20 = takeAway / 20;
int amount10 = (takeAway - amount20*20) / 10;
```

correctly calculates the number of $10 and $20 bills.

```
int amount5 = (takeAway - amount10*10) / 5;
```

is incorrect because you do do not subtract the values of the $20 bills, only the $10 bills. You make a similar error calculating the $2, ie. you do not account for $20 and $10. The error compounds for the $1.

You could try something like:

```
    int amountFifty = changeOwed / 50;
    double takeAway = changeOwed - (amountFifty * 50);
    int amount20 = takeAway / 20;
    takeAway -= (amount20 * 20);
    int amount10 = takeAway / 10;
    takeAway -= (amount10 * 10);
    int amount5 = takeAway / 5;
    takeAway -= (amount5 * 5);
    int amount2 = takeAway / 2;
    takeAway -= (amount2 * 2);
    int amount1 = takeAway / 1;
```